# Quit third-party application on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu

How can I end an application with nodejs.

Example:
I want my application to close Google Chome.

Application is running on linux, xubuntu.

I am developing my application in NODEJS.

tks

Comment: [Check this out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34101/exit-google-chrome-from-terminal) and use it with `child_process`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't *exactly* right but should point you in the right direction

```
// Define Chrome as a child process
var proc = require('child_process').spawn('Google Chrome');

// Then later on
proc.kill();
```